# PHP / MySQL script for sending e-mails - one mail too many

Tags: php, mysql, mailer

I made PHP script to send report from MySQL database to users e-mails. Every user must recieve only their own data (with their id). 
Script tabela.php make html table with user content.

```
<?php

//select data
$sql = "SELECT oports.id, oports.handlowiec, oports.data_rozp, oports.data_przed, oports.nazwa, oports.city, oports.nip, oports.inic, db_users.email FROM oports, db_users WHERE db_users.id = oports.user_id and db_users.id = '{$sqlid}'";

//execute query
$wynik = $polaczenie->query($sql);

//make table schema
echo "<p style=\"font-size:14px;\">There is your report:<br></p>";
echo "<p>";
echo "<table boder=\"1\"><tr>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f4df8b\"><strong>ID</strong></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f9d74d\"><strong>name</strong></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f4df8b\"><strong>Date started</strong></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f9d74d\"><strong>Date deadline</strong></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f4df8b\"><strong>Company name</strong></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f9d74d\"><strong>City</strong></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f4df8b\"><strong>NIP</strong></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f9d74d\"><strong>Initials</strong></td>";
echo "</tr>";

//loop for show data in table
 while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($wynik) ) {
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f7e8ab\">" . $row[0] . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=\"#fbe383\">" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f7e8ab\">" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=\"#fbe383\">" . $row[3] . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f7e8ab\">" . $row[4] . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=\"#fbe383\">" . $row[5] . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=\"#f7e8ab\">" . $row[6] . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=\"#fbe383\">" . $row[7] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<p style=\"font-size:10px;\">Jest to e-mail wygenerowany z systemu CRM. Prosimy na niego nie odpowiadać</p>";

 ?>
```

Script sender.php send data to user:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

//connect with database
$polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

//set charset to show polish letters
$polaczenie->set_charset("utf8");

//check connection
if ($polaczenie->connect_errno!=0)
    {
        echo "Error: ".$polaczenie->connect_errno." Opis: ". $polaczenie->connect_error;
    }
    else 
    {
        //define id variable
        $sqlid = 1;

        //select emails for user with id = sqlid
        $zap = "SELECT email from db_users where id = '{$sqlid}'";    

        //make query (for while loop)
        $zapt = $polaczenie->query($zap);

            //while there are some data, make instructions in loop
            while (($zapt -> fetch_assoc()) !== null)
            {
                    //there are results
                    //execute query again (without this loop do not work properly)
                    $zap = "SELECT email from db_users where id = '{$sqlid}'";
                    //show email and save to variable rowxx
                    $zapx = mysqli_query($polaczenie,$zap);
                    while ($rowx = mysqli_fetch_assoc($zapx)) {
                        print_r ($rowx);
                        $rowxx = $rowx["email"];
                    }
                    //include content of tabela.php
                    ob_start();
                    include "tabela.php";
                    $content = ob_get_clean();

                    //define mail headers, subject and message
                    $od  = "From: itest@mail.pl \r\n";
                    $od .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
                    $od .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n"; 
                    $to = $rowxx;
                    $subject = "Raport szans";
                    $message = $content;

                    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $od)) 
                    {
                        echo "Mail sent!";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        echo "Error with sending!";
                    }

                    $sqlid++;
                    $zapt = $polaczenie->query($zap);

            }
                //else

                echo 'No results';


        $polaczenie->close(); 
        }

?>
```

Script works fine, but send one mail too many for user with last id. If there are 4 users, last receive two mails instead one - first with correct data and second with no data (empty table). 
The output of sender.php script is:

```
Array ( [email] => ika1@mail.pl ) Mail sent!Array ( [email] => pb1@mail.pl ) Mail sent!Array ( [email] => rr1@mail.pl ) Mail sent!Array ( [email] => pr1@mail.pl ) Mail sent!Mail sent!No results
```

So I see that in last "Mail sent" there is no e-mail address, but I receive it on pr1@mail.pl. Why?

Comment: `while (($zapt -> fetch_assoc()) !== null)` seems suspect... why not just `while($zapt->fetch_assoc())` as `false !== null`

Comment: why do you use the nested while's with the same query? The possible SQL injections within the SQL is also suspect..

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I made changes in my code according to your comments (simplified while, delete nested whiles) and change order of queries in while loop - and now works perfectly, but before I add answer I would like to know how it is possible to SQL injection in my script? I do not have any $_POST or $_GET so how to inject code there? Of course printing e-mails in output of script is needed only for debugging now. This script will be added to Cron or Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made changes in my code (simplified while, delete nested whiles and change order of queries in while loop which was reason for sending one mail too many) and now it works perfectly, but I still don't know how is SQL injection possible, because there is no POST or GET.

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

//connect with database
$polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

//set charset to show polish letters
$polaczenie->set_charset("utf8");

//check connection
if ($polaczenie->connect_errno!=0)
    {
        echo "Error: ".$polaczenie->connect_errno." Opis: ". $polaczenie->connect_error;
    }
    else 
    {
        //define id variable
        $sqlid = 1;

        //select emails for user with id = sqlid
        $zap = "SELECT email from db_users where id = '{$sqlid}'";    

        //make query (for while loop)
        $zapt = $polaczenie->query($zap);

            //while there are some data, make instructions in loop
            while ($rowx = $zapt -> fetch_assoc())
            {
                    //show e-mail recipient (for debug only)
                    print_r ($rowx);
                    $rowxx = $rowx["email"];

                    //include content of tabela.php
                    ob_start();
                    include "tabela.php";
                    $content = ob_get_clean();

                    //define mail headers, subject and message
                    $od  = "From: itest@mail.pl \r\n";
                    $od .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
                    $od .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n"; 
                    $to = $rowxx;
                    $subject = "Raport szans";
                    $message = $content;

                    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $od)) 
                    {
                        echo "Mail sent!";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        echo "Error with sending!";
                    }

                    //increment sqlid
                    $sqlid++;

                    //execute query again
                    $zap = "SELECT email from db_users where id = '{$sqlid}'";
                    $zapt = $polaczenie->query($zap);

            }
                //else

                echo 'No results';


        $polaczenie->close(); 
        }

?>
```